# How to calculate the size of an elasticsearch node?

Tags: elasticsearch, shopware

How can i calculate the needed size of the elasticsearch-node for my Shopware 6 instance when i known some KPIs.

For example:

| KPI | Value |
| --- | --- |
| **Customer** | 5.000 |
| **Products** | 10.000 |
| **SalesChannel** | 2 |
| **Languages** | 1 |
| **Categories** | 20 |

Is there a (rough) formula to calculate the number of documents or the required size of a node?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.elastic.co/blog/benchmarking-and-sizing-your-elasticsearch-cluster-for-logs-and-metrics is relevant

however what you have provided there is only logical sizing of the data. you will need to figure out what this all means when you start putting documents into Elasticsearch

Comment: Yes, but this is a product-related posting. So there should be a way to calcuate it. I was hoping someone from Shopware is reading here and can answer that question.